# Function definition not found for #define

Tags: c++, macros

I am getting a weird error for one of my macros. The names are changed, but besides that the code is exactly the same as the one in my project. Its purpose is automatic a process I write many times troughout my code.

```
#ifdef add
#undef add
#endif
#define add(name, temp)             \
struct name<temp>                   \
{                                   \
    static constexpr r = true;      \
}
```

**Here is the error:**

```
Function definition for 'add' not found.

explicit type is missing ('int' assumed)
```

It's expanding the code properly and showing me that too, but it seems either it is very confused about what's going on or I do not understand the error.

I am using Visual Studio 2019, so the VC++19 compiler.

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've forgotten `bool` keyword as compiler message suggested but as `int`

```
#ifdef add
#undef add
#endif
#define add(name, temp)             \
struct name<temp>                   \
{                                   \
    static constexpr bool r = true;      \
}
```